Rudin theorem $6.19$.
There is theorem $6.12$ : Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak {M}$ in $X$. Then there is a measurable function $h$ such that $|h(x)| = 1$ for all $x \in X$ and such that $$ d \mu = h d |\mu|.$$
There is the definition of $C_0(X)$:
A complex function $f$ on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is said to vanish at infinity if to every $\epsilon \gt 0 $ there exists a compact set $K \subset X$ such that $|f(x)| < \epsilon $ for all $x$ not in $K$.
The class of all continuous $f$ on $X$ which vanish at infinity is called $C_0(X)$.
There is our theorem:
If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then every bounded linear function $\Phi$ on $C_0(X)$ is represented by a unique regular complex Boreal measure $\mu$, in the sense that $$ \Phi f = \int_X f d\mu $$
for every $f \in C_0(X)$. Moreover, the norm of $\Phi$ is the total variation of $\mu$:
$$ || \Phi || = |\mu|(X).$$
There is the proof:
We first settle the uniqueness question. Suppose $\mu$ is a regular complex Borel measure on $X$ and $\int f d\mu = 0 $ for all $f \in C_0(X)$. By Theorem $6.12$ there is a Borel function $h$, with $|h| = 1 $, such that $ d \mu = h d |\mu|.$ For any sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $C_0(X)$ we then have $$ | \mu |(X) = \int_X (\bar{h} - f_n) h d |\mu| \leq \int_X | \bar{h} - f_n| d |\mu|$$, and since $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^{1}(|\mu|)$ , $\{f_n\}$ can be so chosen that the last expression tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.
I don't understand why is $|\mu|(X)$ equal to $\int_X  (\bar{h} - f_n) h d |\mu| $.
Any help would be appreciated.

I think the idea is that $\int f_nh d|\mu|=\int f_n d\mu = 0$ by assumption and $\int_X \bar{h} h d |\mu|=\int_X 1 d |\mu|=|\mu|(X)$.

Since $\int_X f_n d\mu=0$, then we have
$$\int_X f_n d\mu =\int_X f_n h d|\mu| \Rightarrow \int_X f_n d|\mu|=0,$$
then we have;
\begin{align*}
h |\mu|(X)&= \mu(X) -0\\
&=\int_X (1)d\mu-\int_X f_n d|\mu|\\
&= \int_X \overline{h} hd\mu-\int_X f_n d|\mu|\\
&= \int_X (\overline{h}- f_n) h d\mu\\
&=\int_X (\overline{h}-f_n)  d|\mu|.
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$|h||\mu(X)| \leq \int_X |\overline{h} -f_n| d|\mu| \Rightarrow \mu(X) \leq \int_X |\overline{h} -f_n| d|\mu|$$

why is $|\mu|(X)$ equal to $h\mu(X) - 0 $?
